# My app leaks Bitmaps of random shapes that I don't have in my drawable folder

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I have a strange memory leak problem where my app keeps leaking `Bitmap` objects and other objects related like `VectorDrawables`, `AnimationDrawables`

I have via `Eclipse Memory Analyzer` and Gimp been able to recover the leaked `Bitmap` objects and found out that they are random shapes of stars, and squars or circles. I dont have any of these shapes in my `res/drawable` folders.

Where do they come from and why are they leaking so much?
This leak happend on my `Samsung Galaxy S7 - Android 7.0` and on emulator with `Android 7.0` and 6.0. But there are no leaks when I run my app on a Huawai running `Android 4.4.4`

Here is a link to my hprof. file if someone would take a closer look: https://www.dropbox.com/s/e1ry3ny5eb66xk8/out3%20-%20Kopi.hprof?dl=0

**Screenshot of the Dominator Tree from the Memory Analyzer**

They yellow marked is forexample the stars below this picture

[image]

**Bitmap of stars found in my leaks**

[image]

Also my stacktrace keeps spitting these lines out endlessly

```
 03-21 17:00:08.415 16747-16747/muddzdev.shoppist I/InputMethodManager: [IMM] startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
    03-21 17:00:08.428 16747-16760/muddzdev.shoppist D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=98
    03-21 17:00:13.315 16747-16886/muddzdev.shoppist E/OpenGLRenderer:   saveGfxinfoFileDisabled enabled
    03-21 17:00:13.632 16747-16886/muddzdev.shoppist E/OpenGLRenderer:   saveGfxinfoFileDisabled enabled
    03-21 17:00:13.914 16747-16886/muddzdev.shoppist E/OpenGLRenderer:   saveGfxinfoFileDisabled enabled
    03-21 17:00:14.257 16747-16886/muddzdev.shoppist E/OpenGLRenderer:   saveGfxinfoFileDisabled enabled
    03-21 17:00:14.592 16747-16886/muddzdev.shoppist E/OpenGLRenderer:   saveGfxinfoFileDisabled enabled
    03-21 17:00:14.933 16747-16886/muddzdev.shoppist E/OpenGLRenderer:   saveGfxinfoFileDisabled enabled
    03-21 17:00:15.299 16747-16886/muddzdev.shoppist E/OpenGLRenderer:   saveGfxinfoFileDisabled enabled
```

Comment: Same problem here, my log is spammed by "OpenGLRenderer:   saveGfxinfoFileDisabled enabled" and I dont know how to remove it. S7 with Android 7.0 as well..

Comment: @Xys It took me a week to solve. I have posted the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this problem is so hard to debug and it took me a whole weeks work on it. This leak came out of no where and `CanaryLeak` can't even detect it.

I uninstalled Android Studio, deleted all remaning folders in the pc that is under AppData in your `User` folder and everything else related to Android or Android Studio under your `C:/User` and `Program files` and even the SDK folder.

Made a full clean up of the register with `CCleaner` and then downloaded Android Studio again, cloned my project from Git and then I ran my app again and here it was! NO LEAKS AT ALL.

I'm pretty sure that this crazy leak has nothing to do with your own app but something with Android Studio or something completely else

Answer (score 14):

I had the same issue with the S7 after updating to API 24, I was able to remove this error by disabling the GPU monitor in Android Studio. Looks like it definitely is an android studio issue, perhaps only with the S7.

Comment: Nice! but it also happend with the emulator! On Samsung it happends with the endless error stack traces, but not with other phones or emulator, but they do still leak if you look in the monitor

Comment: I think we should make a issue case on this

Comment: disabling the GPU monitor in Android Studio solved the issue to me