# What is the meaning of E/OpenGLRenderer: saveGfxinfoFileDisabled - enabled showing up too many times in logs

Tags: java, android, android-7.0-nougat

I tried a lot to look out for the meaning of this error . But could find anything on this. Can please some one throw some light on this E/OpenGLRenderer: saveGfxinfoFileDisabled enabled i am getting too many red lines showing this error. how ever the android application is running fine I am just curious to know why my log is filled up with this E/OpenGLRenderer: saveGfxinfoFileDisabled enabled red lines . It showed up when the device was updated to Nougat

Comment: Same happened to me. Apparently someone managed to fix it by reinstalling android studio : http://stackoverflow.com/a/43009413/5120292

Comment: Thank you Xys, that was a great link . did it work for you ?